# Counterexample for Dirichlet product of two completely multiplicative functions.

Tags: number-theory

The below text is the proof of why Dirichlet product of two multiplicative functions are multiplicative:

[image]

It's obvious how the assumption of $(m,n)=1$ allowed the proof to be proceeded. However I am trying to find a counterexample to show that the Dirichlet product of two completely multiplicative functions is not be always completely multiplicative, but I couldn't succeed. Considering f and g to be power functions, $n^a$ and $n^b$ respectively, don't help since I can't find a way to decompose the double sum but it doesn't mean that $h(mn) \ne h(n)h(m)$. Is there any elementary counterexample?

Comment: Take for example $n\to n$ the identity function; than you can see that $I*I(n)=nd(n)$ which is not completely multiplicative

Comment: Consider $h(mm)$. In equation, in the term after third $=$ sign, when $d \mid a$, $d \mid b$, term $f(d)g(m/d)f(1)g(m)$ will be present twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime and $h = f * g$, $h(p) = f(1) g(p) + f(p) g(1) = g(p) + f(p)$ while $h(p^2) = f(1) g(p^2) + f(p) g(p) + f(p^2) g(1) = g(p)^2 + f(p) g(p) + f(p)^2$, so for $f * g$  to be completely multiplicative we'd need $f(p) g(p) = 2 f(p) g(p)$, and thus $f(p) = 0$ or $g(p) = 0$.

Comment: I understood all except for the last conclusion; why f(p)=0 or g(p)=0 leads to contradiction? Is it because we hadn't considered them to be zero? by the way, if f(p)=0 or g(p)=0 it doesn't make them not completely multiplicative.

Comment: I didn't say $f(p) = 0$ or $g(p)  = 0$ leads to a contradiction.  I said if  $f * g$ is to be completely multiplicative we need $f(p) = 0$ or $g(p)=0$.

Comment: $f(p)g(p)=0$ is also a sufficient condition for $f*g$ to be completely multiplicative. (provided f and g are completely multiplicative)

Answer (score 1):

(as formal series)

if $f(n)$ is multiplicative then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s} = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(p^k) p^{-sk}\right)$$

if $f(n)$ is completely multiplicative then $f(p^k) = f(p)^k$ and $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(p)^k p^{-sk} = \frac{1}{1-f(p)p^{-s}}$ hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s} = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \left( \frac{1}{1-f(p)p^{-s}} \right)$$

finally if $f,g$ are completely multiplative and $h = f \ast g$  :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty h(n) n^{-s} = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n) n^{-s}\right) = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \left( \frac{1}{(1-f(p)p^{-s})(1-g(p)p^{-s})} \right)$$

which is not the Euler product of a completely multiplicative function, except if for each prime $p$ : $$f(p)g(p) = 0$$

Answer (score -1):

A counterexample is $I: \mathbb N\mapsto \mathbb N$ you have :
$$\forall n\in \mathbb N \quad \quad (I*I)(n)=nd(n) $$
and we know that $n\mapsto nd(n)$ is not completely multiplicative because $d$ the divisor counting function is not completely multiplicative.

Comment: what is $d(n)$?

Comment: $d$ is the divisor counting function, $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ , you can compute $I*I$ and deduce what $d$ means :)